# Ubuntu One Music App for Android: missing folders

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

The Android music app doesn't show many of the music folders on Ubuntu One. Both the available and the missing files are inside the same synched parent folder.

1. The files are supported and DRM-free (mostly `.mp3`)
2. The missing files and folders are visible in the ubuntu one files web interface (I haven't tried the Android file app nor synched another desktop, though)
3. The same thing happens when using the original subsonic Android app.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the missing files stored in folders shared with you, as opposed to folders associated with your own account?  If so, then what you are seeing is the expected behaviour:

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-cant-i-see-music-files-that-are-folders-shared-with-me/

If the files are in a folder you own, please file a support request with the following form:

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

The music streaming service works off metadata scraped from the music you've updated (which is separate from the file metadata used by the main storage service.  It is possible that something has got stuck and needs a kick to rescan your folders.